# Unsupported Media Type Error in AJAX-Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass string to controller use of Ajax Stringify but i got this error 
**415 (Unsupported Media Type)** 
My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType : 'json',
     url: "addSample",
     data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
     cache : false,
     beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     },
     success : function(response) {
         console.log("Success: "+ response);            
     },
     error : function(xhr) {
         console.log("Sorry, there was a problem! " + xhr.responseText);
     },
     complete : function() {
         console.log("Request complete");
     }
});
```

Passing the String :

```
var search = {
     " name" : "aa",
      "sname": "bb",
      "dname" : "cc"
}
```

My spring controller function:

```
@RequestMapping(headers={"Accept=application/json"},value = "addSample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String addData(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody final DemoDTO demoDTO)
    {
        return  "{\"value\":\"true\"}";
    }
```

My DTO:

```
public class DemoDTO implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String sname;
    private String dname;
  //getter setter
}
```

Please help me for solving this....

Comment: where is method for request addCourseStructure your method is for value = "addSample" request

Comment: Sorry that my mistake,typing mistake.But in my code it is correct.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the `jackson-core` and `jackson-mapper` jars in your project? These are responsible for automatically converting JSON to DTOs and vice versa. If you're using Maven, these should be defined as dependencies in the `pom.xml`

Comment: @WillKeeling I have use those jars in my project .Iam using jackson mapper library is jackson-core-2.3.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
beforeSend : function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 },
```

With this:

```
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
```

Also, remove `headers={"Accept=application/json"}` from spring controller so it would be as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addSample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String addData(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody DemoDTO demoDTO)
{
    return  "{\"value\":\"true\"}";
}
```

Comment: Finally I have got the data ,I have added jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar and its working fine,Thank you all for hepling me ..........